# Encoding issue: Bookdown + DataTables (DT) + cetain chapter name

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, bookdown

I use an *R* *Bookdown* package to create an HTML-based Git-book. The book contains an interactive HTML table created with function `DT::datatable()`.
I noticed, that if any chapter name in a book contains an international letter (say, "ą", "ž", etc.), the interactive table becomes encoded incorrectly.

**Is there a way to have international letters in chapter names and a correctly encoded interactive table (DataTable)?**

Structure of my *Bookdown* folder:

```
dir()
[1] "_bookdown.yml"   
[2] "_output.yml"  
[3]  "bookdown_tmp.Rproj"
[4] "index.Rmd"
```

**_bookdown.yml:**

```
documentclass: book
output_dir: "_book"
encoding: utf-8
```

**_output.yml:**

```
bookdown::gitbook: default
```

**index.Rmd** (that gives correct result)**:**

````
--- 
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---

# Ch1

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(DT)
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Lithuanian")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
x <- c("ą č ę ė į š ų ū 9 0 ž", "3254")
DF <- data.frame(x = x)
datatable(DF)
```
````

Result:
[image]

If in file **index.Rmd** the line with the title `# Ch 1` is changed into chapter name that contain international symbols, say, `# Ch 1 ž`, the encoding issues arise:

[image]

Nothing else is changed except from one additional letter in a chapter's name.

I render the book by pressing "Build book" button in *RStudio*: [image]

---

Session information `devtools::session_info()`:

```
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.0.136)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       Europe/Helsinki             
 date     2017-02-01                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version  date       source                            
 backports   1.0.5    2017-01-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 bookdown    0.3.9    2017-01-31 Github (rstudio/bookdown@b73daa1) 
 devtools    1.12.0   2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 digest      0.6.12   2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 evaluate    0.10     2016-12-27 Github (hadley/evaluate@742da2d)  
 htmltools   0.3.5    2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 knitr       1.15.8   2017-01-31 Github (yihui/knitr@b936c1e)      
 magrittr    1.5      2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 memoise     1.0.0    2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 Rcpp        0.12.9   2017-01-14 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 rmarkdown   1.3.9002 2017-01-31 Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@c4908dc)
 rprojroot   1.2      2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 rsconnect   0.7      2016-12-21 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 stringi     1.1.2    2016-10-01 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 stringr     1.1.0    2016-08-19 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 withr       1.0.2    2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                    
 yaml        2.1.14   2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
```

Comment: Can you please post the encoding of both Rmd files - the one without and the one with the international character in the header (use the `file` command in the shell - the `file.exe` is stored in the bin folder of Rtools and git when you use Windows). I bet it is different.

Comment: Does `x <- iconv(x <- c("ą č ę ė į š ų ū 9 0 ž", "я л ю", "3254"), to = "UTF-8")` work? If not add encoding of your Rmd file as from param (e. g. `from = "ISO-8859"`)

Comment: To narrow down the problem: Add a code chunk at the end to print x in both files. Does it print the characters correctly?

Comment: In both cases `shell("file index.Rmd")` results in `index.Rmd: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`.

Comment: And in both cases `print(x)` results in `[1] "ą č ę ė į š ų ū 9 0 ž" "3254"`. Just adding the result of `print(x)` also distorts encoding of `DT::datatable` table. I  am starting to think, that some intermediate file produced by `rmarkdown` has incorrect encoding.

Comment: `x <- iconv(x, to = "UTF-8")` does not help.

Comment: I lost my bet ;-) If you copy both Rmd files and change the header to generate a simple HTML markdown (`output: html_document`). Does this render the characters correctly. If not, look at the HTML source,  are the characters embedded correctly as string? And does the header contain `<meta charset="utf-8">` or another charset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134621/discussion-between-r-yoda-and-vilmantas).